# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::last_query()

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, fatal-error

```
       `$query = $this->db->from('user_notifications');
        $query = $query->select('user_notifications.*,users.Firstname as name');
        $query = $query->order_by('user_notifications.date_added','desc');
        $query = $query->get();
        echo $query->last_query();
       return $query->result_array();`
```

**error =  Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::last_query() in**

*Thank you in advance*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the syntax will be

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

see the link http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using codeigniter & Active Record you can echo the last query by calling

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

And is there a reason to assign the outcome of each line to `$query` ? See below how you can use Active record , Also you query will through the error because you have select `users.Firstname`  in `select()` but in your `from('user_notifications')` you haven't mentioned the users table also if there is relation between them do a proper join by seeing usage of Active record

```
   // function start

   $this->db->select('user_notifications.*,users.Firstname as name');
   $this->db->from('user_notifications,users');
   $this->db->order_by('user_notifications.date_added','desc');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   echo $this->db->last_query();
   return $query->result_array();
   // function end
```

[**Active Record**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)